# Inverting $6 \times 6$ complex matrix on the ARM Cortex M4F processor

Tags: matrix, c, beamforming

I want to invert a $6 \times 6$ complex matrix on the [ARM Cortex M4F](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ARM_Cortex-M) processor. I have the C code to invert a real matrix using the [CMSIS](https://developer.arm.com/tools-and-software/embedded/cmsis) library. Has anyone written a similar C code for complex matrices? Can the  CMSIS library be used to do complex matrix multiplications?

Comment: Here, Asking for code written to your specification is explicitly off-topic. Also, have you incorported the comments you got on your identical https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/632579/6x6-complex-matrix-inversion-on-the-arm-cortex-m4f-processor ?!

Answer (score 2):

If you have a library for real-valued inversion you can expand your matrix  (A) from 6x6 complex to be a 12x12 real-valued matrix (B) using

```
B=[ Real(A)   -Imag(A); 
    Imag(A)    Real(A)]
```

Once you have the inverse you can convert back to complex accordingly.

Comment: This worked. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Is there a way this can be optimized? I have to calculate the inverse of the entire 12x12 matrix. Instead is there a method wherein we can calculate the inverse of half of the matrix instead?

Comment: Unfortunately, there are not short-cuts for this. The complexity of inverting a 6x6 complex-valued matrix is the same as the complexity of a 12x12 real-valued matrix.

Answer (score 1):

I’m not sure it’s as specific as you need it, but Dave Stewart wrote the [*Meschach*](http://homepage.divms.uiowa.edu/%7Edstewart/meschach/html_manual/manual.html) library that includes `zm_inverse()` which takes the inverse of a complex matrix.

All of it is written in `C` and the source code is freely available.